# Android table list

Tags: android

Мне нужно создать в ui табличку которая заполняется динамически, заранее неизвестно сколько в таблице будет строк - известно только сколько будет полей(столбцов)
Я думаю создать layout- вверху сделать шапку таблицы, а потом с помощью ListView сделать строки. Дайте совет, так правильно делать, или лучше как-то по-другому. Просто я редко  динамически рисовал layout и не совсем это приятно делать.

благодаря Barmaley все получилось. здесь конечно примитив, но принцип работает

```
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(MapActivity.this);
        final View tableMapDialogView = factory.inflate(R.layout.table_requests, null);
        tableDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapActivity.this).create();
        tableLayout=(TableLayout)tableMapDialogView.findViewById(R.id.TableLayout1);
        final View item = factory.inflate(R.layout.row_table, null);
        final TextView avatar = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.textAvatar);
        final TextView v = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.textV);
        final TextView b = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.textB);
        final TextView c = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.textC);
        final TextView price = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.textPrice);
        avatar.setText("kakDelddddddddda");
        tableLayout.addView(item,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tableDialog.setView(tableMapDialogView);
        tableDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делаешь 2 разных лейаута:

1. Собственно таблица
2. Строка таблицы

Далее создаешь таблицу и динамически по ходу оперы через `inflate()` создаешь строку и добавляешь к таблице через `addView()`

Comment: спасибо. так сделаю

Comment: прошу прощения, может глупый вопрос, а как сделать шапку таблицы, чтоб потом она была на одном уровне со строками?

Comment: используй и для шапки и для строк одинаковый лейаут и все будет тип-топ

Comment: ))) получилось. осталось только сделать все красивым по дизайну) спасибо. оно выравнивается автоматически